# Maya 2012 to MD5 exporter ( export multiple meshes)

Tags: 3d, maya, away3d

Currently I'm doing a 3d avatar creation and customization using flash, (away3d and md5) .. I'm designing characters using  MAYA 2012 and I'm going to export it as MD5 format.

However current MAYA-MD5 Exporter which I've found from (http://www.zbufferstudios.com) only can export only 1 mesh on export.

How can I export from maya2012 to md5 with **multiple meshes support**?

Comment: Where's the programming part of your question?

Comment: actually these maya exporters using the coding script as maya plug in

Answer (score 0):

As you stated these plug-ins are actually .mel scripts. I'm actually looking for something similar, and have only found this [updated version](http://www.doom3world.org/phpbb2/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=13164). If you come across something that works more efficiently please do let us all know.

Hope that helps though.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be some MD5 exporters written as C++ Maya plugins out there, I think from the Quake Rally team; will run faster than MEL, perhaps, but more of a pain.  In either case easiest way is probably to do an additional MEL or Python script, go through the selection list and call the export function on each mesh.